# .NET SDK 3.0.100 will not appear in Dropdown Options in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, razor, sdk

I just installed .NET Core Installer: x64 onto my computer because I am about to start dabbling with Razor for a project.  However, when I try to to create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application, I go to the dropdown menu and ASP.NET Core 3.0 does not appear. I just see other versions of the SDKs that I have such as ASP.NET Core 2.2 and 2.1.  How can I fix this issue?

I have provided some more info below:

```
Project Info:
Will be made with ASP.NET Core Web Application.
Visual Studio: 2019
Location of where SDK is installed:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100
```

I am running Windows 10 on my iMac.

Answer (score 1):

Per Microsoft's [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0.0/3.0.0.md)...

> Visual Studio compatibility: .NET Core 3.0.0 requires Visual Studio 2019 16.3 GA to take full advantage of all its features. .NET Core 3.0.0 will not work properly in earlier versions of Visual Studio.

To make sure you are running the latest version of Visual Studio save your work and go to Help > Check for Updates. Upgrading from 16.2.5 to 16.3.0 fixed it for me.